# HTML <pre> tag add empty line

Tags: html

I have a question about the pre tag in HTML.
My code looks the follow

```
<pre>
 User              |   Account              |   Active
 ----------------------------------------------------------------          
   Tim             |    1234                |    yes
   Bob             |    0346                |    yes
   Adams           |    1765                |    no
   Gig             |    0045                |    yes
</pre>
```

but as output i have

```
 User              |   Account              |   Active

 ----------------------------------------------------------------  

   Tim             |    1234                |    yes

   Bob             |    0346                |    yes

   Adams           |    1765                |    no

   Gig             |    0045                |    yes
```

there is an empty line in between of each line in the  tag.

My css looks like:
pre { overflow-x:scroll}

i have also tried display:inline but does not work.

Can someone please help me to remove the empty line in the output?
Thanks :)

Comment: Try referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315150/removing-spaces-in-pre-tag-html) for how to use the pre tag

Comment: Hi. I had a look at the link you provide. I guess my problem is that the extra lines are generated by the output. Do the is a simple way to remove them that do not require a function or javascript? should be possible by setting the properties of the pre element, i guess

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was setting the `line-height` style property:

```css
   pre {
      line-height: 100%;
      overflow-x: scroll;
   }
```